'AvailabilityInternalLegacy.h: No such file or directory' error when running C++
I am running my C++ project via CLion. I use the g++ compiler and have the defaults set for the CMake and ninja toolchains in CLion. It used to work totally fine till now, but recently I installed some other compilers for some other work. When I tried to run this project again later, it seems that the defaults got messed up and now I get this error.
I have tried to reinstall gcc and unlink and link gcc again. I also tried brew cleanup gcc but to no avail. Further, the error gives me no clue on what may have been messed up. I can try to manually install AvailabilityInternalLegacy.h, but I don't want such a 'hacky' fix because my C++ project used to work completely fine before. It is only now that it has started to give this error.
Not sure if this is relevant, but note that the files go from opt/homebrew to Apple's CommandLineTools when finding wchar.h. The relevant line is
#if _GLIBCXX_HAVE_WCHAR_H
#include <wchar.h>
#endif

This is defined in the file /opt/homebrew/Cellar/gcc/13.2.0/include/c++/13/aarch64-apple-darwin23/bits/c++config.h
/* Define to 1 if you have the <wchar.h> header file. */
#define _GLIBCXX_HAVE_WCHAR_H 1

/Applications/CLion.app/Contents/bin/cmake/mac/aarch64/bin/cmake --build /Users/USERNAME/CLionProjects/Project/cmake-build-debug --target file -j 8
[1/2] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/file.dir/file.cpp.o
FAILED: CMakeFiles/file.dir/file.cpp.o 
/opt/homebrew/bin/g++-13   -DLOCAL -g -std=gnu++14 -arch arm64 -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX13.3.sdk -fdiagnostics-color=always -MD -MT CMakeFiles/file.dir/file.cpp.o -MF CMakeFiles/file.dir/file.cpp.o.d -o CMakeFiles/file.dir/file.cpp.o -c /Users/USERNAME/CLionProjects/Project/file.cpp
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX13.3.sdk/usr/include/Availability.h:166,
                 from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX13.3.sdk/usr/include/wchar.h:72,
                 from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/gcc/13.2.0/include/c++/13/cwchar:44,
                 from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/gcc/13.2.0/include/c++/13/bits/postypes.h:40,
                 from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/gcc/13.2.0/include/c++/13/iosfwd:42,
                 from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/gcc/13.2.0/include/c++/13/ios:40,
                 from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/gcc/13.2.0/include/c++/13/ostream:40,
                 from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/gcc/13.2.0/include/c++/13/iostream:41,
                 from /Users/USERNAME/CLionProjects/Project/file.cpp:5:
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/gcc/13.2.0/lib/gcc/current/gcc/aarch64-apple-darwin23/13/include-fixed/AvailabilityInternal.h:185:10: fatal error: AvailabilityInternalLegacy.h: No such file or directory
  185 | #include <AvailabilityInternalLegacy.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.

I would sincerely appreciate some help regarding this.

You get conflicts between AppleClang and GCC SDKs. I suggest that you remove GCC and use AppleClang that is the native development tool on macOS.

@273K Thank you for your reply. Indeed, switching to Clang does work. However, I must to use GCC instead. Do you know any way I could remove this conflict? Thanks

Who said you must use GCC? If it's your instructor, change him. He should teach you the standard C++, not a compiler.

@273K It's not any instructor. Instead, I want to use GNU PBDS data structures provided by #include <ext/pb_ds/...> which is not available for Clang.

Use boost, a more portable library.

How exactly have you set the compiler for your project? According to parameter -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX13.3.sdk CMake assumes that you use given SDK and its compiler.

@Tsyvarev I haven't explicitly set any of these things. I have left them to defaults. Answering your question, my CMake says -DCMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT:PATH=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX13.3.sdk

@Tsyvarev Do you think this could be changed to something else?

why would you include both gcc headers and macos SDK that is meant for clang at the same time?

@haleyk i have only included iostream

@MangoPizza sry i meant lookup from both gcc and mac sdk

@273K I hear Apple Clang is crippled and backwards. I don't have a Mac to check it though.

You probably should not use gcc with this sysroot, such combination is unlikely to work. Try to compile a hello world program from the command line, no cmake or any other fancy build system.

(Based on the suggestions in this forum thread)
In the settings dialog, get to your CMake configuration, and do one of the following:

Set the environment varible CPATH to ${darwin.Libsystem}/include (but manually expand yourself the darwin.Libsystem variable to the actual path on your system! It might be something like /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include); or
Add -DCMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES=${darwin.Libsystem}/include to your CMake command line. Again, don't the dollar-sign and variable name, you need to actually expand that to a proper full path.

These two should be equivalent but I'd try the second.
